# Use ">>" Redirection Operator for Non-Existent File In tcsh/csh

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, tcsh

I'm writing tcsh scripts and I would like to append to a log file, but if the log file doesn't exist before appending to it, I get an error (reproduced below). In bash the file gets created if it doesn't already exist. Does tcsh support this feature or do I have to ensure that the file exists before appending to it?

Is there a way to use the `>>` operator in tcsh similar to bash?

```
$ echo something >> file_that_does_not_exist
file_that_does_not_exist: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

> *`command`* `>>!` *`log_file_name`*

Or this for redirecting stderr as well

> *`command`* `>>&!` *`log_file_name`*

See `csh(1)` and/or `tcsh(1)`, [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/csh) and [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh), for example.